# Tracking Competitors Facebook Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

Is there a way to track the number of likes on a Facebook fan page that I am not an admin on? I understand how to use the analytics on a page when I am an admin of the page but in the interest of competitive analysis, I was wondering if there are any tools of this nature.

I thought maybe there was a Chrome plugin or something of that nature that could take a snapshot of a page to track the competition. Any ideas on what exactly I should be looking for or if it exists? Thanks!

---

### EDIT

I've using the Google Docs spreadsheet:
http://labs.met.cz/#fbfanscounter

This graphs "likes" via the Facebook API. I'm wondering if there is a way to set it to save the data every day for a certain Facebook ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. For anybody else looking for this answer, here is a great link:

http://socialfresh.com/facebook-page-competitive-analysis-tools/

I am using the Wildfire one and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on a few things. Firstly, if the page is under your control then you can simply let Facebook alert you of new activity - they send out regular reports on page activities.

If the page is not under your administration then you'd have to consider if the page is public. If it is like the [coca-cola page](https://www.facebook.com/cocacola), then data can be requested at any time simply via this URL - `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola`

```
{
   "id": "40796308305",
   "name": "Coca-Cola",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174560_40796308305_2093137831_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
   "likes": 42106778,
   ...
}
```

With regard to mapping likes to certain users -
This is not possible.  Only the administrators of a page can see exactly who has "liked" the page.  The only way to see if a page is liked by a specific person is if **that** user grants an application permissions to view their "likes".

### TL;DR

- You can't see who liked a page unless you administer that page.
- You can only tell if a specific user has liked a page and that requires the `user_likes` permission.

Comment: Ah yeah that's a good resource. Thanks. I found that the Wildfire website actually does exactly what I was looking for a graphs everything beautifully.